# Java application refresh itself

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I'm trying to develop a desktop java application for borrowing books in Library, I want the program to refresh itself for example every 10 Minutes, and check the database to find whether any borrowed books return-date has passed current date or not.

I have used Thread, however, an exception occurs which said the connection is timed out

```
   public void checkDB(){
    Thread clock = new Thread(){
       public void run(){
        for(;;){
        String checkOnLoanBooks = "SELECT ....";
        PreparedStatement onLoanStmt = conn.prepareStatement(checkOnLoanBooks);
        onLoanStmt.setString(1, "No");
        onLoanStmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(fromDate.getTime()));
        onLoanStmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(toDate.getTime()));
        ResultSet onLoanRs = onLoanStmt.executeQuery();
        if(!onLoanRs.next()){} else {
            do{
             // Getting data from DB
              }while(onLoanRs.next());

           try {
                 sleep(100000);
               } catch (InterruptedException ex) {      

              Logger.getLogger(BorrowHome.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
            }
          }
        };
       clock.start();
       }
```

Comment: Just establish a new connection for each iteration.

Comment: why not replace the `for(;;)` with a `while` loop

Comment: Pool your connections -> take connection, use it, return to the pool. Keep repeating that every time.

Comment: Many thanks for your responses I have used pooled connection and established and closed for each iteration. Now it works for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are not closing the connection with the database, so it is closing it by itself due to the long period of time waiting: `sleep(100000);`.

You should always open the connection, do the operation and then close it.

Comment: Thanks Pedro closing the connection was one of the problem.